# Dynamic query from internal table

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I had a requirement in which I wanted to dynamically run this query. Has anyone have worked on this kind of query?

```
READ TABLE table_name TRANSPORTING feild_name INTO table_name
              WITH KEY key_feild1 = value1,
                       key_feild2 = value2,
                       key_feild3 = value3.
```

Comment: What part do you need to be dynamic?

Comment: they key part is where i am struggling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a READ TABLE statement be created dynamically with an arbitrary number of key field specifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869119/can-a-read-table-statement-be-created-dynamically-with-an-arbitrary-number-of-ke)

Comment: @suncatcher: Please do not add deprecated tags to questions. Read the tag wiki/description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more possible solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18888463). Though, it is a bit ugly, but it definitely works.

```
DATA: table_tab TYPE TABLE OF rsdstabs,
      selid     TYPE  rsdynsel-selid,
      cond_tab  TYPE rsds_twhere,
      field_tab TYPE TABLE OF rsdsfields,
      string    TYPE string.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <cond>  LIKE LINE OF cond_tab.

table_tab = VALUE #( ( prim_tab = 'USR02') ).

CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT'
  EXPORTING
    kind         = 'T'
  IMPORTING
    selection_id = selid
  TABLES
    tables_tab   = table_tab
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS       = 4.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE 'Error in initialization' TYPE 'I' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  LEAVE PROGRAM.
ENDIF.

CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_DIALOG'
  EXPORTING
    selection_id  = selid
    title         = 'Free Selection'
    as_window     = ' '
  IMPORTING
    where_clauses = cond_tab
  TABLES
    fields_tab    = field_tab
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS        = 4.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE 'No free selection created' TYPE 'I'.
  LEAVE PROGRAM.
ENDIF.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fld> TYPE any.
DATA: field1  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value1 TYPE string,
      field2  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value2 TYPE string,
      field3  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value3 TYPE string,
      field4  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value4 TYPE string,
      field5  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value5 TYPE string,
      field6  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value6 TYPE string,
      field7  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value7 TYPE string,
      field8  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value8 TYPE string,
      field9  TYPE c LENGTH 10, value9 TYPE string,
      num1(1) TYPE n,
      fldname TYPE fieldname,
      valname TYPE fieldname.

ASSIGN cond_tab[ tablename = 'USR02' ] TO <cond>.

IF sy-subrc = 0.
  LOOP AT <cond>-where_tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_cond>).
    num1 = sy-tabix.
    CONCATENATE 'field' num1 INTO fldname.
    CONCATENATE 'value' num1 INTO valname.
    ASSIGN (fldname) TO <fld>. "assigning field name
    string = <fs_cond>.
    REPLACE REGEX `(^.*\(\s)(.*)(EQ.*)` IN string WITH '$2'.
    <fld> = string.
    ASSIGN (valname) TO <fld>. "assigning value
    string = <fs_cond>.
    REPLACE REGEX `(.*EQ\s)'(.*)('\s*\))` IN string WITH '$2'.
    <fld> = string.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.

SELECT * 
  FROM usr02
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_usr).

READ TABLE lt_usr ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_usr>)
WITH  KEY  (field1) = value1
           (field2) = value2
           (field3) = value3
           (field4) = value4
           (field5) = value5
           (field6) = value6
           (field7) = value7
           (field8) = value8
           (field9) = value9.
```

The sample is built on USR02  table.

1. At first, on the dynamic selection screen we specify necessary selections fields (keys for READ TABLE) and their values.
2. Then `FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT` FM builds WHERE condition based on these fields.
3. We parse this condition and fetch populated field names and values.
4. In a `READ TABLE` statement template, empty fields are simply ignored and table is read only by populated keys.

Answer (score 4):

`READ TABLE` has dynamic syntax when specifying secondary keys ([here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenkeyname.htm)) and key components ([here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abapread_table_key.htm)), but in a limited fashion.

I think `LOOP AT` is the command you are looking for. More details about the usage and example [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abaploop_at_itab_cond.htm). Look at Part 4:

> Dynamic WHERE Condition cond_syntax can be specified as a
>   character-like data object or standard table with character-like row
>   type

Dummy code:

```
LOOP AT table INTO line WHERE (condition).
  EXIT. --> Exit at first found line.
ENDLOOP.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
...
ENDIF.
```